# Rerender when global variable change

Tags: reactjs

I want to rerender my component, when a global variable change. My code now looks like this

```
window.loading = true;

setTimeout(() => {
  window.loading = false;
}, 4000);

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { rerender: window.loading }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{`Loading: ${this.state.rerender}`}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

But nothing happens, eventhough I can see that the window.loading updates in console.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using React Hooks

```
const ChildComponent = ({ fuse }) => {
  const [legalText, setLegalText] = useState([]);

  window.loading = () => {
    setLegalText(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('legal')));
  };
}
```

We created a global function inside the ChildComponent. All you need to do is call window.loading anywhere in the app and this function will fire.

Definitely use redux, mobX, or context API. There are edge cases where this is handy

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make your Component be re-rendered after a global property changes you should use Promise, RxJS or any other Observer like pattern.

somwhere in code:

```
window.loading = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 300);
});
```

in your component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  state = { isLoaded: false }

  componentDidMount() {
   window.loading.then(() => 
     this.setState({isLoaded: true})
   )
  }


  render() {
    const {isLoaded} = this.state;
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

This way you can make your component re-render after some global property changed (resolved). The key is to use Promise instead of bool primitive

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the global variable as a prop to your component. Currently your state does not updates itself hence it does not re-render itself.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
}

render() {
return ( <h1>{`Loading: ${this.props.rerender}`}</h1>)
}
}
```

And when the component is created pass it as a props:

```
 <MyComponent rerender={window.loading }
```